# Any equivalent of * style in Bash for acting on mutliple files NOT matching the same pattern

Tags: python

I'm looking to iterate a script over all files in the present working directory *without* iterating over scripts (so any extension `.py`). I was prevously using this

```
for fileName in os.listdir('.'):
    if fileName != 'autocorrelation1.py':
        with open(fileName, "r") as input:

        REST OF SCRIPT HERE
```

Which worked when I only had the one script autocorrelation.py in the folder, but now I have a few python scripts I was wondering if there were a bash-style equivalent of `*` for example

```
for fileName in os.listdir('.'):
    if fileName != *'.py':
        with open(fileName, "r") as input:

        REST OF SCRIPT HERE
```

I guess I am being lazy and could do it in another line of code but was just wondering if anyone knew a more fun way!

Comment: small stylistic point: open() defaults to `r` so you could leave it off if you liked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend using the [fnmatch](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch) module:

```
for fileName in os.listdir('.'):
    if not fnmatch.fnmatch(fileName, '*.py'):
        print fileName
```

---

The [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module could help you find matching files, if that was what you wanted:

```
for fileName in glob.glob('*.py'):
    print fileName
```

Comment: `glob` is the way to go here if we just want python files. Note that the `iglob` version is probably better since that returns an iterator.

Answer (score 6):

In this particular case, the easiest solution is

```
if not file_name.endswith(".py"):
```

An alternative is

```
if not fnmatch.fnmatch(file_name, "*.py"):
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) with wildcards to check a set (or subset) of files and [endswith()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=endswith#str.endswith) to filter `.py` files.

e.g.,

```
import glob

for fn in glob.glob('*'):  # specify set of files to check
   if not fn.endswith('.py'): 
      print(fn)
```

Code updated in accordance with updated/clarified question.

This [Python Module of the Week](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/glob/) has more examples using glob

Comment: Downvotes without explanation don't help ***anyone*** (OP, SO or me). How does `glob` not apply here? I'm happy to correct omissions or improve the answer if errors are pointed out. The currently highest rated answer (posted at the same time) uses `glob` in the same manner.

Comment: @DonCallisto Yes, makes no sense and without *any* reasons *serves absolutely no purpose*. I guess it's easy when you can stay anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the glob module, I'd suggest looking at these [generators](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/). Specifically this one:

```
# genfind.py
#
# A function that generates files that match a given filename pattern

import os
import fnmatch

def gen_find(filepat,top):
    for path, dirlist, filelist in os.walk(top):
        for name in fnmatch.filter(filelist,filepat):
            yield os.path.join(path,name)

# Example use

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lognames = gen_find("access-log*","www")
    for name in lognames:
        print name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re` module, you can find it [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

```
re.search('^.*py$',str(yourFileName))
```

And this is the output:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> a = re.search('^.*py$','prova')
>>> a
>>> a = re.search('^.*py$','prova.py')
>>> a
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x2b09559c1760>
```

Comment: If I had to guess: there is no benefit from using `re` over the other solutions. REs are quite expensive...

Comment: That's right. And besides, in similiar contexts, REs and knowledge about them can be very useful.

Comment: Downvotes should be reserved for incorrect answer or answers that do not apply to OP's question, otherwise it seems petty.

Comment: @Levon i agree with you, but evidently someone thinks differently